# Spring boot actuator loggers

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I check my loggers on web through spring actuator, there are two types of levels: configuredLevel, effectiveLevel. What is the difference between them? And what is the common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loggers inherit the log level from the parent logger (e.g. ROOT)

**configuredLevel** has a value when the log level was explicitly set to the logger or null if the inherited level is used.

**effectiveLevel** contains the actual log level. if no log level was set to the logger it will have inherited value otherwise it will have configuredLevel.

Example output:

```
{
  "levels": [
    "OFF",
    "ERROR",
    "WARN",
    "INFO",
    "DEBUG",
    "TRACE"
  ],
  "loggers": {
    "ROOT": {
      "configuredLevel": "TRACE",
      "effectiveLevel": "TRACE"
    },
    "org.example": {
      "configuredLevel": null,
      "effectiveLevel": "TRACE"
    },
    "com.example": {
      "configuredLevel": "INFO",
      "effectiveLevel": "INFO"
    }
  }
}
```

For "com.example" the INFO level was set, "org.example" uses the inherited value from the ROOT logger.

Answer (score 3):

Configured level is the level of configuration if you configured it one specifically
If not when you:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/actuator/loggers/YOUR_CLASS
```

you will get something like this:

```
  {"configuredLevel":null,"effectiveLevel":"INFO"}
```

INFO is the default configuration for loggers in spring.

If you change it to something specific like WARN you will get

```
{"configuredLevel":"WARN","effectiveLevel":"WARN"}
```

I don't know exactly what you mean by ***what is the common***, hope i answered it above.